# android get color list from resource

Tags: android, gridview, colors, adapter

I have an array with names and color codes. I want to color the cell in gridview with colors taken from array. I created this code but I get NPE, this is the error:

Logcat Output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 11:03:30.513 25902-25902/? E/AndroidRuntime:
at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:211)
```

Color XML File:

```
 <array name="colors">
<item name="White">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</item>
    <item name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</item>
    <item name="Yellow">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="Snow">#FFFAFA</item>
    <item name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</item>
 </array>
```

SourceCode:

```
public class ColorPickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      private Context context;
      private List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      public ColorPickerAdapter(Context context) {
           this.context = context;
           String colors[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);

           colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // add the color array to the list
           for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                colorList.add(Color.parseColor(colors[i]));
            }
           [..]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your resources seems wrong. What you should do

**METHOD 1**

In colors.xml

```
<color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
<color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
<color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
<color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
```

In arrays.xml :

```
<array name="colors">
    <item>@color/Ivory</item>
    <item>@color/LightYellow</item>
    <item>@color/Yellow</item>
    <item>@color/Snow</item>
</array>
```

Then access using

```
int[] colors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors);

for (int i = 0; i < tileColumns; i++) {
    colorList.add(colors[i]);
}
```

**METHOD 2**

Do not specify the name of the differents colors

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>#FFFFF0</item>
        <item>#FFFFE0</item>  
        <item>#FFFF00</item>
        <item>#FFFAFA</item>
        <item>#FFFAF0</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and use it using

```
String colors[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// add the color array to the list
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colorList.add(Color.parseColor(colors[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your array in the following way:

```
   <string-array name="colors">  
        <item>#FFFFFF</item>  
        <item>#FFFFF0</item>  
         ...
   </string-array>
```